# how to check if some characters are in an string?

Tags: php

we have an string like :

```
$string="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";
```

so i want to check if some words are available in that string. for example the words :

```
$words=['Ipsum','54'];
```

and you can see `Ipsum` is in the string but `54` is not in string, so the function should call back `true` (because `Ipsum` found).
I'm using php, thanks for helping.

Comment: *** `$words = array('Ipsum','54');`

Comment: create a function yourself and put strpos in it

Comment: You should use strpos, run foreach() for $words array and use strpos inside foreach.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4366748/7008354) question from the sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
php > $string="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";
php > $lookfor = "simply";
php > echo strpos($string, $lookfor) > 0 ? true : false ;
1
php > $lookfor = "simplest";
php > echo strpos($string, $lookfor) > 0 ? true : false ;
//nothing will be printed -))
```

just make a function from above snippet.

**update**

```
$ cat search.php
<?php

$domain="asdasd asd fasdfasfafafad f454   asdfa";
$lookfor=array('as','f454');

function containsOneOfThoseWords($str, $words) {
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if (strpos($str, $word) !== false) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

echo containsOneOfThoseWords($domain, $lookfor);
?>
$ php search.php; echo 
1
```

Comment: `strpos` could also return `0`, which is perfectly fine, if the search word is at position `0` - you should check against `false` and not `> 0`

Comment: yeah that's right -))

Comment: thanks for helping but see this code : ali98.xyz/filter.txt , it didn't work!

Comment: you should pass arguments to your `containsOneOfTheseWords` function. I've fixed it - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop combined with `strpos` should be all you need to achieve this

```
function containsOneOfThoseWords($str, $words) {
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if (strpos($str, $word) !== false) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping but see this code : https://ali98.xyz/filter.txt , it didn't work!

Comment: @AliYQB You shoud pass the arguments to the function... `containsOneOfThoseWords($str, $words)`